# Why laravel select and group by return same value

Tags: mysql, laravel

I try to select count and group with Laravel query, but they are return same value with different field.

This is my code:

```php
$kategoris = ['NUK', 'Hubkel', 'Sta_kawin'];

foreach ($kategoris as $kategori) {
    $raw[] = 'count('.$kategori.') as '.$kategori;
}
$implodeRaw = implode(', ', $raw);

$desas = DB::table('arts')
           ->select('arts.id', 'KDKEC', 'KDDESA', DB::raw($implodeRaw))
           ->where(['KDKEC' => $kodeKecamatan])
           ->groupBy('KDDESA')
           ->orderBy('KDDESA', 'ASC')
           ->get();
```

Result:

```
results: {
    0 => {
        'id': 10
        'NUK': 6
        'Hubkel': 6
        'Sta_kawin': 6
    }
    1 => {
        'id': 13
        'NUK': 1
        'Hubkel': 1
        'Sta_kawin': 1
    }
}
```

So, what's wrong with this code? I want the `NUK, Hubkel, Sta_kawin` return different value because the source data is different.

Comment: did you try flattening the data? like ->get()->flatten(1)

Comment: with flattening or flatten(1) return same value

Comment: I think the sql query didn't return the right value too.  `select arts.id, KDKEC, KDDESA, count(NUK) AS NUK, count(Hubkel) as Hubkel, count(Sta_kawin) as Sta_kawin from arts where (KDKEC = '010') group by KDDESA ORDER BY KDDESA ASC`